# Clicking Objects in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm new to Actionscript 3 and I'm trying to learn as much as I can.

I want to know how to move objects by clicking.

For Example: I will first click on object to select it then I will click on another object(not in the same location) to place the first one on top of it.

*Sorry if my explanation is bad

I don't have the code to show you because I don't know how to do it.

But the way that I thought of is: 


 - I will click on the first object to select it and that object will go to an array

 - That array will have the function of the second click which will transfer the object on top of another one.

The problem is that there is chance that i can select two objects on the first one (It should be only one). Is there any way to fix this? Or is there a way to make this easier?

Comment: What you need here is to apply a Finite State Machine logic here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine

Comment: I get what you mean, and i agree that I need to apply that logic. But I'm asking how to do it code-wise.

Comment: Code-wise you need the click handler function to know which state you are in (initial state, you're waiting for object to be selected, or elevated state, an object is selected, you're waiting for the target) and act differently based on that.